# Why result is that? -2.22044604925E-16

Tags: php, null, while-loop, range, zero

When you use the range function, with a range between zero and 1, incrementing by 0.05 each step, the loop produces an incorrect result when you attempt to minus the current value in the loop from 1.

As you can see below, the last element in the array is the integer 1. The script should echo the result of 1 minus 1. However, for some reason PHP treats 1-1 as -2.22044604925E-16 instead of zero.

### Reproduce code:

```
foreach (range(0,1,0.05) as $t)
    {
    echo (1-$t).'<br />';
    }

Expected result:
----------------
1
0.95
0.9
0.85
0.8
0.75
0.7
0.65
0.6
0.55
0.5
0.45
0.4
0.35
0.3
0.25
0.2
0.15
0.1
0.05
0

Actual result:
--------------
1
0.95
0.9
0.85
0.8
0.75
0.7
0.65
0.6
0.55
0.5
0.45
0.4
0.35
0.3
0.25
0.2
0.15
0.1
0.05
-2.22044604925E-16
```

Comment: I tried your code but I can't reproduce the error, I just get the expected result.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that this is something to do with [PHP Floating Points](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and possibly the CPU that it is being run on. The last number is right on the level where the precision bottoms out e-16. As for the last value, if you understand scientific notation, it's ALMOST zero - and as ALMOST zero as PHP understands.

Comment: When I do round() for the value I get -0 as the last value: http://codepad.org/cojR0z4k

Comment: why my result is -2.22044604925E-16 . what i must do that result is be zero?

Comment: @user2787192 Basically, you must either use some sort of rounding or if you want EXACT values, use integers - or start learning to write code in a language that has a more extensive numeric data type. As far as PHP is concerned, for numbers it either integers or floats :(

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is numeric and having decimal places in PHP is considered a float. Now, you or I might think that floats and decimals are really really accurate - and for us 0.1 simply means 0.1 - but for PHP 0.1 might be shown, but in the background, it actually thinks it is 0.10000000000000000001.

This is to do with [Floating Point Precision.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) which has a big warning on it:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.

The short version is that -2.22044604925E-16 is about as ALMOST ZERO as PHP understands, but somewhere along the way, it lost the exactness of what it was doing and came up witht he wrong answer.

This is the same problem that covers pretty much all systems that do not have either integer or fixed decimal data types. For example, look at [mySQL data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) which has integer types, fixed point types (both labelled as EXACT Values) and finally floats which are labelled as approximate types.

By the way, your value of

> -2.22044604925E-16

is actually:

> -0.000000000000000222044604925

Comment: Fluffeh Thank you. I Answered me very well.

Comment: No worries, sadly, the short version is that PHP doesn't do decimals very well at all. :(

Comment: Also (as this is your first question), if you feel that this is correct and has answered your question, it's great to [Accept the Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that other folks don't waste their time trying to answer it further.